# Column reference 'name' is ambiguous

Tags: sql, postgresql

I already read from previous answers here in SO that using an alias in a where statement isn't possible. But I'm wondering how this query can be re-written?

```
      SELECT 
        CASE 
        WHEN app_reports_mgmt.reports.rid = app_reports_mgmt.report_template.rid THEN
        app_reports_mgmt.report_template.name
        ELSE app_reports_mgmt.reports.name   
        END AS name
FROM app_reports_mgmt.reports left join app_reports_mgmt.report_template on app_reports_mgmt.reports.rid = app_reports_mgmt.report_template.rid
where LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%daily%') and app_reports_mgmt.reports.report_status = 'Active' order by name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, the problem is in the `where` clause, not the `order by`.

You could fix this by referencing by position:

```
select (case when r.rid = t.rid
             then t.name
             else r.name   
        end) as name
from app_reports_mgmt.reports r left join
     app_reports_mgmt.report_template t
     on r.rid = t.rid
where (case when r.rid = t.rid then lower(t.name) else lower(r.name) end) like lower('%daily%') and
      r.report_status = 'Active'
order by name;
```